# Are these seedlings Mazari palm or Agave neomexicana?

Tags: identification, succulents, seedlings, container-gardening, palm

A couple of weeks ago I have planted seeds for both [*Nannorrhops ritchiana*](http://www.palmpedia.net/wiki/Nannorrhops_ritchiana) (Mazari palm) and [*Agave neomexicana*](http://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/3151/new-mexico-century-plant/). Unfortunately, I forgot to put proper labels on back then.

I am now seeing two sprouts (currently 2 and 3 cm high, respectively) of one kind but not the other. So which one of the two plants are these going to grow into: Mazari palm or Agave neomexicana?

[image]

Comment: It's the palm, pretty certain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both monocots, but Agave seedlings would have opened out quickly after emerging. They are much slower seedlings.  This must be your palm seedlings. They are looking great, good job! Make sure you give them very bright light, but not full sun for a while.

Palm seedlings:

[image]

Agave seedlings:

[image]